# How to find records in PostgreSQL matching a combination of a pair of nullable String columns

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, string-matching

Suppose a PostgreSQL table, `articles`, contains two nullable String columns of `name` and `alt_name`.
Now, I want to find records (rows) in the table that have

- a **combination of** String `name` and `alt_name` matches another combination of the same type in the same table:

  - i.e., `[a.name, a.alt_name]` is equal to either `[b.name, b.alt_name]` or `[b.alt_name, b.name]`
- where `name` or `alt_name` may be `NULL` or an empty String, and in any circumstances `NULL` and an empty String should be treated as identical;

  - e.g., when `[a.name, a.alt_name] == ["abc", NULL]`, a record of `[b.name, b.alt_name] == ["", "abc"]` should match, because one of them is `"abc"` and the other is NULL or empty String.

Is there any neat query to achieve this?

I thought if there is a way to concatenate both columns with a UTF-8 *replacement character* (`U+FFFD`) in between, where NULL is converted into an empty String, that would solve the problem. Say, if the function were `magic_fn()`, the following would do a job, providing there is a unique column `id`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM articles a INNER JOIN places b ON a.id <> b.id
  WHERE
        magic_fn(a.name, a.alt_name) =  magic_fn(b.name, b.alt_name)
     OR magic_fn(a.name, a.alt_name) =  magic_fn(b.alt_name, b.name);


-- [EDIT] corrected from the original post, which was simply wrong.
```

However, [<strike>concatnation is not a built-in function in PostgreSQL</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12378904/3577922) and I don't know how to do this.
[**EDIT**] As commented by @Serg and in answers, a string-concatnation function is now available in PostgreSQL from Ver.9.1 ([CONCAT or ||](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)); n.b., it actually accepts non-String input as long as one of them is a String-type as of Ver.15.

Or, maybe there is simply a better way?

Comment: PosgreSql string concat oper is [||](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

Comment: [Concatenation **is** a built-in function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.1.1.1.1) - as specified in the SQL standard

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, you're right. I realised it when I saw people's answers. I have now edited the hypothetical code snippet so people will not be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which takes in the `name` and `alt_name`, then returns an aggregated string with `null`s converted to empty strings and the results sorted:

```
create function magic_fn(a text, b text) returns text
  return (select json_agg(t.v) from (
    select t1.* from (
      select coalesce(a, '') v
      union all
      select coalesce(b, '') v) t1 
    order by t1.v) t);
create table articles (id int, name text, alt_name text);
insert into articles values (1, 'abc', null), (2, 'abc', ''), (3, null, 'abc'), (4, 'aaa', 'a'), (5, 'aaa', 'a'), (6, 'a', 'aaa')
```

Usage:

```
select * from articles a join articles b 
on a.id <> b.id and magic_fn(a.name, a.alt_name) = magic_fn(b.name, b.alt_name)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rpI5bigX)

Comment: Confirmed it works, even in edge cases with both columns being null/empty-string; see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x_zRIoZc), where I added two more rows on top of yours. Thanks!

Comment: If an above answer r0esolved you issue please accept it. This helps future questioners with same/similar issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT  *   FROM articles a
cross join articles b    
where  
(ARRAY[COALESCE(a.name,''),COALESCE(a.alt_name,'')] @>  ARRAY[COALESCE(b.name,''),COALESCE(b.alt_name,'')])  
and (ARRAY[COALESCE(a.name,''),COALESCE(a.alt_name,'')] <@  ARRAY[COALESCE(b.name,''),COALESCE(b.alt_name,'')]) 
and a.id<>b.id
and a.id<b.id  --optional (to avoid reverse matching)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rIXPBnYB)

Comment: That's neat! +1 for the option to avoid reverse matching (I didn't know the necessity, but I can guess).

Comment: Oops, I find your example fails when one of them is a combination of `''` (or NULL if coalesced). Basically, `(ARRAY['a', ''] @> ARRAY['', ''])` returns true. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r-3p4zbU) (based on your fiddle, thanks!)

Comment: @Masa Sakano, I did an update on the query. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Fantastic! Confirmed at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y8fB_oRc) So, basically the reverse direction `@<` is required –– I couldn't work out why the original one didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Greatly thanks to your answer, I have come up with another solution (see [my newly posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74415532/3577922), in which I acknowledge you), where [COALESCE()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) is nicely got rid of.

Answer (score 1):

Having reviewed a few answers (special thanks to @MitkoKeckaroski), I have come up with this short solution. [COALESCE()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) is not necessary!

The condition is that the UTF replacement character (`\U+FFFD`) should never appear in the data record, which you can safely assume according to the Unicode specification.

```sql
SELECT * FROM articles a JOIN articles b 
ON a.id <> b.id AND
  ARRAY[CONCAT(a.name, U&'\FFFD', a.alt_name), 
        CONCAT(a.alt_name, U&'\FFFD', a.name)] @>
  ARRAY[CONCAT(b.name, U&'\FFFD', b.alt_name)];
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8NbMYLL) (where I extended the data prepared by @Ajax1234 – thank you!)

Comment: Awesome! Great cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use

- coalesce for convert null to empty
- || for concatenate string

and then compare string like this sql:

```
(coalesce(a.name,'') || coalesce(a.altname,'')) =  (coalesce(b.name,'') || coalesce(b.altname,'')) 
 or 
 (coalesce(a.name,'') || coalesce(a.altname,'')) =  (coalesce(b.altname,'') || coalesce(b.name,''))
```

Comment: Now I understand `CONCAT()` is long [introduced to Postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-concat-function/) since Ver.9.1, thanks. I am afraid your answer wrongly works when the 2-column combination is like `('ab-cd', '-ef')` and `('ab-', 'cd-ef')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from both names, remove null and empty values, then check if the arrays overlap (have elements in common)

```
select *
from articles
where array_remove(array[nullif(name,''), nullif(alt_name,'')], null) && array['abc']
```

This can be made easier by creating a function that generates such an array:

```
create or replace function combine_names(p_names variadic text[]) 
  returns text[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(name)
  from unnest(p_names) as x(name)
  where nullif(trim(name),'') is not null;
$$ 
language sql
immutable
called on null input;
```

By making the parameter `variadic` it's possible to provide a different number of arguments (in theory even more than two)

```
select *
from articles
where combine_names(name, alt_name) && combine_names('abc')


select *
from articles
where combine_names(name, alt_name) && combine_names('abc', null)


select *
from articles
where combine_names(name, alt_name) && combine_names('abc', 'def')
```

Comment: A caveat is it seems not to work in edge cases where both the columns are null/empty-string. Other than that, it works, thanks! See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4bv8Nqyr), where I implemented your algorithm to my question case, including the edge cases.